# Catching keyCode==13 in directive Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have some code

```
app.directive('currencyInput', function ($filter, myFactory) {
return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function () {
            return $filter('number')(ctrl.$modelValue);

        });

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            let plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[\,\.]/g, ''),
                b = $filter('number')(plainNumber);

            elem.val(b);
            //here I need to add listener if keyCode==13
            return plainNumber;
        });
    }
};
});
```

So, I need to catch if keyCode==13. How can I do that in the place where I add a comment? I need to make some actions:

```
 elem.bind('keydown keypress', ($event) => {
  if ($event.which === 13) {
     let val=$element.val();
     if(attrs['param']=="amount") myFactory.process[attrs['param']]=val*24;
     else myFactory.process[attrs['param']]=$element.val();
     let i=0;
     for(let key in myFactory.process){
         if(myFactory.process[key]===""){
               scope.dashboard.currParam=i;//this doesn't works until user make one more action.
               break;
         }
         i++;
     }
  }
 })
```

But not all actions "act" at once user tapped enter. myFactory.process looks like

```
process: {
        cost:"",
        amount:"",
        wrapping:"",
        risk:"",
        limit:"",
        franchise:""
    },
```

This string `scope.dashboard.currParam=i;` must update view(DOM). But it doesn't update until I clicked on the input.

Comment: I don't think you can do it shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in focus. So, you need to make something like:

```
 elem.bind('keydown keypress', ($event) => {
 if ($event.which === 13) {
 let val=$element.val();
 if(attrs['param']=="amount") myFactory.process[attrs['param']]=val*24;
 else myFactory.process[attrs['param']]=$element.val();
 let i=0;
 for(let key in myFactory.process){
     if(myFactory.process[key]===""){
           scope.dashboard.currParam=i;
           let target = $event.target;
           target.blur();//this helps
           break;
     }
     i++;
 }
 }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this code:

```
elem.bind('keydown keypress', ($event) => {
  if ($event.which === 13) {
    scope.$apply(() => scope.$eval(attrs.enter, { $event });
    // enter key pressed here
  }
});
```

Comment: the problem is that after user tapped "enter" I need a function to be done, but it doesn't done until user make one more action(clicking, keydown etc). How can I resolve this?

Comment: update the question, hope you what the problem is ;(

Comment: So, what is myFactory.process, in your code? Is it a list of other keys?

Comment: myFactory is a factory, so process is an object of the factory

Comment: Ok so what does it return? You say it's an object, could you put in your example what it looks like? Also in your code, can you console.log() what val is, is it what you expected?

Comment: Updated question. If keycode==13 I assign property to myFactory.process. Then I check if some properties in this object doesn't set, model need to be updated.